# Efficient database schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization

I have two MySQL tables that storing some data like below :

table INFO:
the "key" must be unique in this INFO table, and "group" can be duplicate for each key.

| info_id: pk | group | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GrA | aaa |
| 2 | GrA | bbb |
| 3 | GrB | ccc |
| 4 | GrC | ddd |

table HISTORY: if the product "product_name" hasn't info_id (using SELECT sql query),
then insert the info_id for product_type.

| index: pk | product_name | group | info_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ProductA | GrA | 1 |
| 2 | ProductA | GrB | 3 |
| 3 | ProductA | GrA | 2 |
| 4 | ProductB | GrA | 1 |
| 5 | ProductC | GrA | 1 |
| 6 | ProductC | GrA | 2 |
| 7 | ProductD | GrC | 4 |
| 8 | ProductD | GrA | 2 |
| 9 | ProductE | GrB | 3 |

running sql query client is python.
above table is working now, but records of INFO table are over 600,000 and records of HISTORY table are over 5,000,000.
the SQL query performance is really slow, one query ends in 5 secs after run the query.
to get faster performance for each query result, I want to rebuilding these schema.

Edit:
Hello,
I'm using below queries:

1. SELECT COUNT(group) FROM INFO : to get count of specific group
2. SELECT * FROM INFO WHERE group = "GrB" and key = "EEE"
3. INSERT INTO INFO(group, key) VALUES("GrB", "EEE") : insert if query 1 result is None
4. SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE product_name = "ProductA" and info_id = "4"
5. INSERT INTO HISTORY(product_name, group, info_id) VALUES("ProductA", "GrC", "4") : insert if query 4 result is None

Comment: Performance does not normally depend on what columns you have. It depends on what your indexes are and what the query looks like.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.
It would help if you could show the SQL query you're trying to run, and the output of EXPLAIN, along with schema information - especially which indexes exist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

I could better explain the problem if you had provided the `CREATE TABLEs` and the `SELECT`.  Meanwhile, I will guess that `key` is either not indexed or indexed by itself.  Based on how you described the table, this would be much faster:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
    key VARCHAR(...) ...,
    grp VARCHAR(...) ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(key),
    INDEX(grp)   -- needed if you ever look up all the keys for a grp
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and replace `info_id` by `key` in the other table.

But then why have grp in both tables?  Show us the schema and query; I may come up with a better way.